# How to make page fill the iPhone5 screen without scrollbar in PhoenGap project?

Tags: cordova

This is part of my html:

```
<body>
    <div id="intro" class="page">
        <div id="slider">
            <div>
                <img src="img/image1.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/image2.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/image3.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/image4.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

I set

```
body{height:100%} 
#intro{height:100%}
```

and in `config.xml`

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

But there's still vertical scrollbar and it can scroll down a little bit.
It seems that the lenght of distance scrolled is twice of the height of the iPhone status bar on the top.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I hide the status bar with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` but no help.

Answer (score 0):

Access the main view and set overflow property

```
.view
{
overflow-y:hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reset the view frame and it works:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,320,screenBounds.size.height);
```